# Semantic-ui form rule only if option is selected

Tags: validation, semantic-ui

I am using semantic ui and am trying to do some form validation with it.

The scenario I have is the user has 2 options: email,or phone app verrifcation. They select one of the options and enter whatever in a text field then click submit.

However I am not sure how to do rules on this with semantic UI.

I know if I wanted to check if it was blank I could do something like this:

```
$('.ui.form')
  .form({
    fields: {
      CODE: {
        identifier: 'code',
        rules: [
          {
            type   : 'empty',
            prompt : 'Please enter your verification code'
          }
        ]
      }  
    } } );
```

However I would like additional rules based upon which option is selected. I have javascript that currently tells me the value of what is selected, and is updated on change. Unsure how to add it into the rules though, so that I can be like -- If phone was select, must be exactly 6 chars long, or IF email was selected, must be 18 chars long (different lengths for different option).

Is there a way to have conditional rules like this? Closet I could find was:

```
depends: 'id'
```

Which checks to ensure it is not empty.

Does anyone know how to have conditional rules such as this based on another form element? I am using the most recent version of Semantic-UI

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by [adding custom rules](https://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/form.html#adding-custom-rules).

```
$.fn.form.settings.rules.atLeastOne = function (value, fields) {
    fieldsToCompare = fields.split(",")
    if (value) {
        // current input is not empty
        return true
    } else {
        // check the other input field(s)
        // atLeastOne is not empty
        atLeastOne = false
        for (i = 0; i < fieldsToCompare.length; i++) {
            // gets input based on id
            if ($("#" + fieldsToCompare[i]).val()) {
                atLeastOne = true
            }
        }
        return atLeastOne
    }
}

$(".ui.form").form({
    fields: {
        number:{
            identifier: "number",
            rules: [{
                type: "exactLength[6]",
                prompt: "number has to be 6 chars long"
            }, {
                // include the input fields to check atLeastOne[email, address, ...]
                type: "atLeastOne[email]",
                prompt: "Please provide an email or a number"
            }]
        },
        email: {
            identifier: "email",
            rules: [{
                type: "exactLength[18]",
                prompt: "email has to be 18 chars long"
            }, {
                type: "atLeastOne[number]",
                prompt: "Please provide an email or a number"
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Note that the function uses the input id as the identifier and not the input name. You might also want to look at [optional fields](https://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/form.html#optional-fields).